# Is it correct to say that threads enable programmers to expose process internals to the OS scheduler?

Tags: multithreading

Is it correct to say that threads were invented to enable programmers to expose process internals to the OS scheduler?

Comment: [not always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads "'green threads are threads that are scheduled by a runtime library or virtual machine (VM) instead of natively by the underlying operating system...'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A traditional non-threaded is actually a program with 1 thread.

Now understanding that, in some OSes, processing in parallel is achieved by running multiple instances of a program. You wouldn't say that is exposing process internals to the OS, yet it is doing exactly the same thing that a multi-threaded program (ie one with OS support for multiple internal threads) does.

All a "threaded" program does is allow for multiple points of execution to occur using the same program instance, instead of starting a whole new process (with all the associated memory and security and other OS support) the threads re-use the same stuff a single process has.

So, really threads were invented to make parallel processing more efficient. (YMMV with some OSes where a process is pretty lightweight in the first place)

Comment: "processing in parallel is achieved by running multiple instances of a program" If you mean via preemptive multitasking, then agree. Threads appear to move the domain of preemptive multitasking down into the processes themselves. In some sense, enabling process internals to leverage the OS scheduler for concurrent programming.

Comment: With regards to your last sentence, I wanted to point to the "Linux philosophy on threads": if you think you need threads, your processes are too fat. And, in fact, threads were introduced in Linux *not* by adding a new kind of scheduled kernel entity, but simply by adding a flag to processes "share your memory with your siblings? (y/n)". [That's a simplified description, of course.] Linux only has one scheduler entity, a "task", and depending on which flags are set, tasks act as processes, threads (share everything), jails, containers, even VMs (share nothing, not even the CPU state), …